# How to write request body with axios?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, axios, http-headers

I'm using firebase-auth and trying to get user data with axios.

I can get response successfully when I use curl command like this.

```
curl 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"idToken":"[FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN]"}'
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-get-account-info

I'm wondering how to change this request using by axios.
I tried but it didn't work.

```
        const url = 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=key
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const body = {"idToken":token}
        axios
        .get(url,token, {
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data: body      
                  })
                .then(res => {
                  console.log(res.data);
               
                }).catch(error => {
                    alert("error");
                })
```

Comment: "it didn't work" isn't enough information.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what doesn't work the way you expect.  If there is an error, show it.  Right now, you are not logging the `error` that could result from the request.  You should also double check by logging that you have the correct values for token and key - we can't do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not pass the body in GET request so you need to use Axios POST request for pass token in body parameters. If you need to use GEt request for same so pass the token in url.

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
};
const body = {"idToken":token}

axios.post( 
  'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=key',
  bodyParameters,
  config
).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add body in a GET request, change it to post and add as the below line

```
let response = await axios.post(url,{data:body});
```